# Replace Eclipse Compiler with AspectJ ajc

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

How can I replace the compiler in Eclipse with ajc so that it compiles as I edit?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to be more specific about what you are looking to have happen.  I think the term you are looking for is eager parsing.  In JDT, files are not compiled as you type, but rather there is a reconcile occurring in the background that does everything except write the bytecode to disk.

I am assuming that you have AJDT installed and your project is an AspectJ project.  AJDT largely provides the same feature, except that it doesn't perform eager parsing inside of pointcuts and declare statements.  It also will not do eager matching of pointcuts.

Are you seeing some different behavior?